# FTP list command output view in Windows Explorer are not in proper format

Tags: windows, ftp, windows-explorer

I'm developing a FTP server. For `LIST` command, response is formatted in the following format.

```
18-06-19 10:41     DIR             0    Backup(D)
31-10-17 08:23                    1412    Backup.bat
```

The above format is not viewable while in folder format using FTP in Windows Explorer.

Can any one please suggest whats the exact format of `LIST` command response which is compatible to command line and folder view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard listing format for FTP `LIST` command. Though there are some widely used formats, which are supported by Windows File Explorer:

- The standard *nix format (used by most FTP servers)

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x 1 user group           0 Jan 23  2019 folder
  -rw-r--r-- 1 user group          23 Jun 05 10:13 name.txt
  ```
- The DOS/Windows format (used by IIS by default – it also optionally supports the format above):

  ```
  01-30-18  04:34PM       <DIR>          folder
  01-02-19  01:12PM                   23 name.txt
  ```

---

Windows command-line client does not care. It displays the listing as it comes from the server, without any attempt to interpret it.

Comment: Okay, :). And one more doubt. Sometimes i m using filezila client to test my ftp server at that time while uploading folder to server "426 connection closed; transfer aborted" message coming in filezila. But downloading always getting success. For uploading only sometimes this issue occurs. How client application works for upload?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a chat. This is Q&A site. If you have a new problem, please post a new question. I do not think your new problem is anyhow related to this question.

Comment: Sorry for that. Thank you martin :)